# configure image slider by dates in prestashop

Tags: slider, prestashop, slideshow

Good morning,

I'm looking to schedule a slider by date. It would be for a Christmas campaign, after these dates return to the old. Is it possible to do it? Does anyone know any module that does it, even if it is paid? Thank you.

Comment: you may write to the PrestaShop version and the modules used?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I had not seen the answer. The prestashop version is 1.6.1.7 for the header module I used Advanced Image slider for your homepage. I have also bought a plugin, it performs this action but it is not responsive. Does anyone know how I could solve it?